# Issue with collection_select / mongoid / mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am having some trouble with a rails project using mongoid.

The problem is when creating/editing a new post.

I would like to select a topic/category for post (entertainment/news/
misc).

At first I tried the method in railscast 238 (near the end) using a
key value

http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid

But I kept getting a BSON ObjectID error.  While searching for a
solution I found topics discussing it, but the fix mentioned is
already in the version of mongoid I'm using.

So I switched things up.  I have no idea if this is good practice or
not, but I ran out of ideas.  Instead of the railscast method, I used
the code below.  However, I get this error...

> "undefined method `metadata' for
>   "4d4165b3fcf1ee14e0000049":String"

```
post model

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :link
  field :title
  field :synopsis
  field :added_on, :type => Date

  validates_presence_of :link

  embeds_many :replies
  embeds_one :topic
end

topic model

class Topic
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :category, :type => String

  embedded_in :post, :inverse_of => :topics
end
```

```
_form.html.erb
        <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :topic_id %>
                <%= f.collection_select :topic, Topic.all, :id, :category, :prompt
=> "Select a Topic" %>
        </div>
```

I have recently tried changing from embedded_in/embeds_one to references_one/referenced_in.  I am also told "Topic.all" is wrong, but I don't know what to change that to to get it to work.

Gemfile information...

```
gem "mongoid", "2.0.0.rc.6"
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.2"
```

Anything stick out?

Edit:

Updated to 2.0.0.rc.7 still can't get it.

Tried the key method in the railscast video just for fun.  Same
"BSON::InvalidObjectId in PostsController#update"  error.

Answer (score 1):

follow the example in the link below which shows how to use embeds_one with a nested form
[mongoid nested form with embeds_one](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/15fa7dda8161144f)

Answer (score 0):

In your class Topic it should be embedded_in :post, :inverse_of => :topic 
You have :inverse_of => :topics but you are using embeds_one :topic not many

Comment: @user650437  I tried doing that before and it didn't work.  Eventually I had to give up on using embedded and switched to referenced.  Not sure if that is good or bad, but it's the only way I could get it to work.